# How to stop / quit all tasks in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I have googled this one thoroughly and cannot find a solution. I have multiple tasks running in Xcode like so:

[image: Cluttered tasks in Xcode]

How can I stop all these tasks other than quit / restart Xcode all-together, which is something that I dont want to do? I am sure there must be a simple solution to this, I just cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

For me quitting Xcode `CMD + Q` and reopening cleared the old defunc tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to stop them all using following XCode short key:

> command + .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I tried this a million times and unfortunately to no avail.